# How to find SUMPRODUCT of two columns in DAX

Tags: dax

I am new to DAX formulas. I am looking to see how I can do an excel equivalent of a `SUMPRODUCT` for the following data:

```
Id | Metric | Weight | Metric times Weight |  
1 | 20% | 30% | 6.0% 

2 | 10% | 20% | 2.0%  

3 | 25% | 20% | 5.0%  

4 | 12% | 10% | 1.2%  

5 | 15% | 10% | 1.5%  

6 | 2% | 10% | 0.2% |  | 


Net | 84.0% | 100.0% | 84.0% (expected Metric*Weight)
```

I need 15.9% which is `SUMPRODUCT(col1, col2)`.

The row total needs to be a `sumproduct()` versus the expected cross product above.

Any hints how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

If the data is on a table called *Table1* then the following DAX formula should work:

```
WeightedAvg := SUMX(Table1, Table1[Metric] * Table1[Weight])
```

Basically, the function SUMX is iterating over the table *Table 1* doing the product of `[Metric] * [Weight]` then once all the iterations are done, the results are added.

If you have a column with the product (as in your example), then you just need to drag that field to the values area of the PivotTable.

Hope this helps!